Interpolating option surface while respecting no-arbitrage conditions
I have data of market prices of puts and calls, in addition to the corresponding strikes and times to maturity.
I can also find the risk-free rate and the price of the underlying.
How can I interpolate the option market price surface while respecting the no-arbitrage conditions?
I’m struggling in particular to impose the constraints related to the partial derivatives.
Thanks

No expert here, but I have never heard reference to an "option market price surface". It is SOP to work with option volatilities and a "volatility surface". I think one convenience of doing so is that volatilities may remain constant (I said "may"!) when the price of the underlying changes; and you can thus compute the (theoretical) option price from that underlying price and vol (and r and time to maturity) for whatever underlying price you plug in.

Once you normalise properly to remove drift effects and dividends, you will need a convex-decreasing in space and increasing in time interpolation.
(basically do in moneyness (to fwd) and not absolute strike)
The only example I've ever found is this: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/228872089_An_Arbitrage-free_Interpolation_of_Volatilities

Yes, I’ve mostly managed to implement the convexity constraint and the bounds. Unfortunately, my optimisation function doesn’t force the bounds to be respected so the interpolated values are sometimes negative.
How would I normalise properly?

Apply a deterministic transformation so that you operate on a Martingale. The conditions are simpler. In you have an equity process, ensure the strike dimension is in forward-moneyness. So the vol at the point (k, t) really means a strike = k F(t).

I see. That is an interesting suggestion. I effectively started implementing that by accounting for the risk-free rate. But I didn’t fully apply the transformation. I’ll test this and report back. Thanks

I am interested in the same topic.
Often you have some kind of stochastic model which you calibrate to fit the option data as closely as possible and then calculate the implied volatility surface implied by that model. In this way you (typically, depending on the model) get an arbitrage free surface.
However, then you typically only match the market prices approximately, so this is not really interpolating the prices.
If you just consider one time to expiry for your option, that is one smile, then there is quite a bit of research on that topic. I recently implemented this article/model by F.Le Floc'h :
https://arxiv.org/abs/2305.13791.
It interpolates option prices for one maturity in an arbitrage free way and the result is three times differentiable, meaning we get construct a smooth density from the resulting curve.
But if you want a full surface the mentioned article is not suitable.
In that case this article of Huge and Andreasen is a classic:
https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1694972.
They don't provide much details in the article, but there are later works expanding on the article. Also using linear interpolation instead of constant interpolation in their calibration procedure stabilized the calibration procedure a bit.
But anyway, their procedure gives arbitrage free prices and thereby volatilities for a full surface on a given grid. The implied density implied by their procedure is not as well behaved (it gives some slight oscillations due to the interpolation used) as in the previous article though. It also seems sensitive to arbitrage, which is probably no surprise since it is an impossible task to fit an arbitrage free model exactly to data which is not arbitrage free.
But it is a well known and used model that might be a good choice depending on your needs.
I also found a very new article trying to accomplish exactly what you want.
https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=4831218.
The author, F Deschâtres, interpolates volatilities, or more precisely variances, directly without using some underlying stochastic model.
He calibrates the entire volatility surface in one go, ensuring no arbitrage of any kind. Then he use some quadratic programming solver for his problem, which could be a bit of an obstacle if you don't have one available.
I have not implemented the article myself yet, but it looks promising to me.
It is a bit technical, but I believe you could find some answers there regarding to your questions on arbitrage conditions.

Thanks for sharing these resources. I had already stumbled upon a few in my research. I’m finding that the challenge is to create an inefficient way to interpolate prices, starting from a data set of arbitrage-free points.
